# hyperlink from ruby not working on Android browser

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

We have developed a site using ruby on rails. From the site it sends some mails to users to activate their account, forgot password etc.

When we take the link from PC or laptop it works fine. But when we take the link from Android phone or tablet, it gives an error

> "**We are sorry but something went wrong**".

Comment: What about posting some html? Or the link it's self?

Comment: What has gone wrong? What do the error logs say?

Comment: the link itself gives an error we are sorry but something went wrong. But the update in the database is happening by using this link

Comment: "we are sorry but something went wrong" is generally a 500 error on the server side. Could you take add the log ? (if you're using heroku, you can get it with `heroku logs --app yourapp -tail`